# How do I move file a to a different partition or device in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rename

I'm trying to move a file from one partition to another in a Node.js script. When I used `fs.renameSync` I received `Error: EXDEV, Cross-device link`. I'd copy it over and delete the original, but I don't see a command to copy files either. How can this be done?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You need to copy and unlink when moving files across different partitions.  Try this,

```
var fs = require('fs');
//var util = require('util');

var is = fs.createReadStream('source_file');
var os = fs.createWriteStream('destination_file');

is.pipe(os);
is.on('end',function() {
    fs.unlinkSync('source_file');
});

/* node.js 0.6 and earlier you can use util.pump:
util.pump(is, os, function() {
    fs.unlinkSync('source_file');
});
*/
```

Comment: And, unlike the other solutions, cleans up the source directory.

Comment: Isn't this very resource intensive?

Comment: util.pump is deprecated. use is.pipe(os) and then listen to the 'end' event on the output stream.

Comment: For me it was the input stream that was sending the `end` event not the output stream. So: `is.pipe(os)` and `is.on('end', function(){});` worked.

Comment: Why do you use `fs.unlinkSync` and not `fs.unlink`?

Comment: Is possible to move file from local machine to server?

Comment: this isn't a suitable replacement for fs.renameSync, because it isn't synchronous.

Answer (score 8):

One more solution to the problem.

There's a package called [fs.extra](https://npmjs.org/package/fs.extra) written by "coolaj86" on npm.

You use it like so:
`npm install fs.extra`

```
fs = require ('fs.extra');
fs.move ('foo.txt', 'bar.txt', function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    console.log ("Moved 'foo.txt' to 'bar.txt'");
});
```

I've read the source code for this thing. It attempts to do a standard `fs.rename()` then, if it fails, it does a copy and deletes the original using the same `util.pump()` that @chandru uses.

Comment: By the way, I've spoken to coolaj86 on github and he is aware that util.pump() is deprecated in node 0.10 and will be fixing that shortly.

Comment: The author of the fs-extra package is jprichardson and coolaj86 is a contributor (see https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra for more).

Answer (score 7):

I know this is already answered, but I ran across a similar problem and ended up with something along the lines of:

```
require('child_process').spawn('cp', ['-r', source, destination])
```

What this does is call the command `cp` ("copy"). Since we're stepping outside of Node.js, this command needs to be supported by your system.

I know it's not the most elegant, but it did what I needed :)

Comment: this is fine if you don't need to support Windows

Comment: @Lloyd so it's fine always :D

Answer (score 4):

to import the module and save it to your package.json file

```
npm install mv --save
```

then use it like so:

```
var mv = require('mv');

mv('source_file', 'destination_file', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('file moved successfully');
});
```

Comment: this isn't a suitable replacement for fs.renameSync, because it isn't synchronous. https://github.com/andrewrk/node-mv/issues/9

Answer (score 4):

I made a Node.js module that just handles it for you. You don't have to think about whether it's going to be moved within the same partition or not. It's the fastest solution available, as it uses the recent `fs.copyFile()` Node.js API to copy the file when moving to a different partition/disk.

Just install [`move-file`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/move-file):

```
$ npm install move-file
```

Then use it like this:

```
const moveFile = require('move-file');

(async () => {
    await moveFile(fromPath, toPath);
    console.log('File moved');
})();
```