# Execute 'mv' command common in Bash, Zsh, PowerShell, CMD

Tags: node.js, bash, powershell, cmd, zsh

Im trying to create CLI using node.js and I have some tasks where I need to move a folder from one place to another. So to achieve this I used node.js's `child_process`. Like this:

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

function moveFolder(folder,destination){
    exec(
        `mv ${folder} ${destination}`,
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Move error");
            }
            console.log("Move success");
        }
    );
}
```

This piece of code works when I execute this with bash terminal (git-bash or in Linux). But when I execute it using CMD or PowerShell it throws an error

> 'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I know PowerShell and CMD have a command called `move` to achieve this, and that's why it is throwing the error. But is there a way (library or some other method) to execute these types of commands in all environments? (in Windows (CMD, PowerShell), Linux (bash, zsh), Mac OS (zsh)). How can I achieve this?. Can we detect the shell type and execute different commands?

Comment: Consider letting node take care of it, see this thread: [How do I move files in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579055/how-do-i-move-files-in-node-js)

Comment: consider utilizing [shelljs](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) it provides portable Unix shell commands (such as [`mv`](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs#mvoptions--source--source--dest) plus others) for node.js.

Comment: If you do not delete the default alias list from PowerShell, you will find that `mv` is aliased to `Move-Item` if you are on Windows. On Linux (and presumably on Mac OS), it will _not_ be aliased, as that would block the native `mv` command. However, one must be careful about using aliases that match commands from other environments, as the cmdlet that the alias expands to may not be (probably won't be) fully compatible with the command from the other environment.

Comment: 'move-item' is only aliased in PowerShell 5.x. In PowerShell core the alias was removed.

Comment: @Moerwald The [PowerShell-6.2.1-win-x64.msi](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.2.1/PowerShell-6.2.1-win-x64.msi) still ***HAS*** the alias `mv` assigned to `Move-Item`

Comment: Using aliases is asking for trouble. If the code is PowerShell, use `Move-Item`.

Comment: @lotpings, also under Linux?

Comment: The [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)) function on Win uses value of `process.env.comspec` - the default on Win is `cmd.exe`. See [source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/af883e1f99598492474c13447e2a1895c0c6f1b7/lib/child_process.js#L477). Running `node -p "process.env.comspec"` via _PowerShell_ prints something like;`C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`. So the `Move-Item` v's `mv` debate seems irrelevant as node (on Win) will only understand _cmd.exe's_ `move` unless the `shell` option is defined differently.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to highlight in my previous comment  is that even though you may be invoking _nodejs_ via _PowerShell_ it will use `cmd.exe` as that's the default shell it utilizes on Windows.