# How to upload files sent with FormData through Axios ? (TypeError: file.mv is not a function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, form-data

So i am sending a file from one server to another using Axios, one is an app backend and the other is a blockchain server.

Where i am sending the file :

```
router.post("/acme/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {

    var formData = new FormData();
    console.log(req.files.file)
    formData.append("image", req.files.file.data);
    var Response;

    try {
      Response = await axios.post(BC_SERVER + "acmeDataFileUpload", {
        id: req.params.id,
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error BlockChain");
    }

    try {
      res.status(201).send("ok");
    } catch (e) {
      res.status(500).send(e);
    }
  });
```

Where Axios is sending it :

```
app.post('/acmeDataFileUpload', async (req, res) => {        
    const id_owner = req.body.id;
    console.log(req.body)
    const file = req.body.data;
    const fileName = id_owner;  
    const filePath = 'files/' + fileName;
    console.log(fileName);

    file.mv(filePath, async (err) => {
        try {
            const fileHash = await addFile(fileName, filePath);
            fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            });
            const json = '{"dataType": "Object" , "local": "'+localServer+fileHash+'",' +'"ipfsServer": "'+ipfsServer+fileHash+'"}';
            console.log(json);
            const obj = JSON.parse(json);
            res.status(201).send(obj);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Error : failed to download file');
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });


});
```

and this is what the log of `req.body` is like :

```
{
  id: '5ec2b7d47ae93a49ecb773f6',
  data: {
    _overheadLength: 144,
    _valueLength: 579564,
    _valuesToMeasure: [],
    writable: false,
    readable: true,
    dataSize: 0,
    maxDataSize: 2097152,
    pauseStreams: true,
    _released: false,
    _streams: [
      '----------------------------383350625990492694059785\r\n' +
        'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      [Object],
      null
    ],
    _currentStream: null,
    _insideLoop: false,
    _pendingNext: false,
    _boundary: '--------------------------383350625990492694059785'
  },
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
}
```

Basically i am sending the buffer here, since FormData doesn't accept a file and tells me **source.on is not a function** i would rather my image is send to `req.files` instead of `req.body`, Axios is really confusing me.

Comment: As you can see, the "file" object doesn't have the  "move" method. I think you can move your file using the NodeJs file object. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579055/how-do-i-move-files-in-node-js

Comment: Remove the `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` header. The `FormData` request body will set this correctly for you, including the mime boundaries

Comment: have you considered using a middleware like https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
headers: formData.getHeaders()
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: It was crystal clear to me, fixed my issue. ; but yes of course @ysf is right. Just 1 line of text would have been nice.