# How to move a local image file to another folder using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server-side, fs

So I uploaded an image file and store it in a local folder, the assignment requirement is to move the image file from folder A to folder B, I have no clue to do this.

```
app.get('/fineupload003',function(req,res){

    function moveApprovedFile(file, uuid, success, failure) {
        var sourcePath = uploadedFilesPath;
        var desPath = 'approved';
        var desDir  = desPath + "/";
        var fileDes = desDir + file.name;

        fs.access()
    };
});
```

Comment: Check this out as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579055/how-do-i-move-files-in-node-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the requirements is to just move the file and not copy it, you could rename the file which would act as moving.

```
fs.rename(sourcePath, desPath);
```

Read more on rename: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback

Comment: Can cause error:  "EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted"
In case of moving to another partition