# How to move a file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to move a txt file from drive `c` to drive `d` and I found this code by searching but it does not work properly.
please guide me.
Thanks

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script language="JScript">
      function move() {
        var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var file = object.GetFile("C:\\1.txt");
        file.Move("d:\\");
        console.log("File is moved successfully");
      }
    </script>
      <button onClick="move()">Move File txt</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ActiveX is no longer supported.

Comment: Are you testing this in a browser that _supports_ ActiveX in the first place ...? (Which would only be old Internet Explorers, I think, they did not even implement those in Edge to begin with. And all other browsers have never supported this.)

Comment: @Filburt What is the alternative? How can I do this?

Comment: And can be dangerous. JavaScript runs within a sandbox. JavaScript is probably not the right programminf language for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Thomas  Well, it is if you use Node.. :)

Comment: You cannot and should never interact with the file system with client side JavaScript. JS is sandboxed in the browser, use Node.js instead.

Comment: @CBroe What is the alternative? How can I do this?

Comment: @Thomas   True., but you said Javascript.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips of all friends

Comment: @Keith True :) but he tries to run it in a browser.

Comment: I know what's he's trying to do @Thomas  , but what other language would you suggest if he's using HTML then?

Comment: @Keith to be honest, I can't think of any within the browser.

Answer (score 3):

**Browsers do not provide any features that let code provided by a webpage move files the users' hard disks.**

---

The code you've found may have worked in old versions of Internet Explorer (I think the feature was removed in later versions) but only when the security settings were altered from the default to allow it.

You could probably use it in server-side Classic ASP (but then it would move files on the server rather than the client).

---

For a browser-style UI which can do this, look to tools like [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) which pair a custom browser with Node.js in a desktop application. You can then use [the Node.js side of your custom application to move files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579055/how-do-i-move-files-in-node-js).

Obviously this will require that the user download and install your application and use that instead of their web browser.