# Node.JS fs.rename doesn't work

Tags: node.js, file-io, debian

Renaming a file on Debian Wheezy does not work using fs.rename or fs.renameSync.

This only happens in files moved from /tmp/ to another location.

The reported error is: EXDEV, cross-device link not permitted.

Comment: You can see that. I think it useful for u

[here][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568689/how-do-i-move-file-a-to-a-different-partition-in-node-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I move file a to a different partition or device in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568689/how-do-i-move-file-a-to-a-different-partition-or-device-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian Wheezy uses tmpfs for the /tmp folder by default.

This can be turned off by modifing /etc/default/rcS.

```
RAMTMP=yes
```

has to be set to

```
RAMTMP=no
```

Comment: The problem is that Node fs.renameSync cannot do cross-device renames, not that some particular machine has tmp on different device. Don't turn off RAMTMP just because this. (Also on current Debian Jessie RAMTMP doesn't work, /tmp tmpfs is configured via systemd.) Use some smarter rename, for example the module  __mv__: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29287813/196206

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution that works for me:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
util = require('util');
...
//fs.renameSync(files.upload.path, "/tmp/test.png");

var readStream = fs.createReadStream(files.upload.path)
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/test.png");

util.pump(readStream, writeStream, function() {
    fs.unlinkSync(files.upload.path);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem when I was not including dirname and relative path to files (from fileRenameScript.js file directory) to the files I was trying to rename.

```
for(let i=0; i<readdirFileNames.length; i++){
     fs.rename(__dirname+”/sample/strings/“+ readdirFileNames[i], 
     __dirname+”/sample/strings/“+  readdirFileNames[i].split(“trashToRemove”).join(“”), 
     ()=>{
        console.log(“File renamed”)
     })
}
```

That’s the code that got rename to work for me. If anyone else sees this issue reference that code to see the level of detail for file names rename requires.

No error provided that file didn’t exist, or anything to explain why the filenames were not changing. Fs rename proceeded just as if it was successful. When I finally got the changes to take, there was zero change in how the code ran, or what was output.

This behavior was witnessed in node v20.2.0 for me.