# Error: EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted, rename '/tmp/ on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, cross-device

I have problem upload file nodejs. i have read 
[stack1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568689/how-do-i-move-file-a-to-a-different-partition-or-device-in-node-js/29287813#29287813) 
and 
[stack2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196163/node-js-fs-rename-doesnt-work). but i think this different case 
on terminal output like this :

```
> Unhandled rejection Error: EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted,
> rename '/tmp/31941-53enly.png' ->
> 'public/files/complaint/Screenshot_2016-05-01_01-16-55.png'
>     at Error (native)
>     at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:681:18)
>     at null.<anonymous> (/home/faris/myprojects/orchestrale-server/routes/complaintimage.js:163:20)
>     at tryCatcher (/home/faris/myprojects/orchestrale-server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/faris/myprojects/orchestrale-server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:502:31)
>     at Promise._settlePromise (/home/faris/myprojects/orchestrale-server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:18)
>     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/faris/myprojects/orchestrale-server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:10)
>     at Promise._settlePromises (/home/faris/myprojects/orchestrale-server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:683:18)
>     at Async._drainQueue (/home/faris/myprojects/orchestrale-server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
>     at Async._drainQueues (/home/faris/myprojects/orchestrale-server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
>     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/faris/myprojects/orchestrale-server/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

my code :

```
  if (_.isEmpty(req.files) == false) {
      var tp = avatar_folder+req.files.file.name;
      fs.renameSync(req.files.file.path, tp, function(err){});
      var avatar = req.files.file.name;
      }
```

code work on another distro like elementary os, but when i run project on debian jessie or ubuntu 16 LTS that error result on terminal.

any body can't help ? that code just run perfectly on elementary os and arch.

Comment: Both questions you link to are caused by the exact same issue (you can't rename files across file systems/partitions). You should try and see if you can configure the upload middleware to use a temporary directory on the same file system as the final location of the files. The reason this may work on other distributions is that some won't create a separate partition for `/tmp`.

Answer (score 18):

Same problem. Workaround: Read the temp file, write the file in new location and remove the temp file:

```
        // Read the file
        fs.readFile(oldpath, function (err, data) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('File read!');

            // Write the file
            fs.writeFile(newpath, data, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
                res.end();
                console.log('File written!');
            });

            // Delete the file
            fs.unlink(oldpath, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log('File deleted!');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, what is `res`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use 'mv' packgage to resolve this issue
Link NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mv
How to use:

Replace some old code with fs.rename:

```
    fs.rename(temp_path, target_path, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('> FileServer.jsx | route: "/files/upload" | err:', err);
            throw err;
        }
    });
```

With:

```
    const mv = require('mv');
    mv(temp_path, target_path, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('> FileServer.jsx | route: "/files/upload" | err:', err);
            throw err;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've been using `fs.rename` with Docker volume bind to copy the uploaded file from `/tmp` to `/app/uploads` directory. This is perfectly solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

it assisted me when working with nodejs , the concept should be the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/43206506/7878987

Comment: Please add some context to your link only answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
var mv = require('mv');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
     console.log(oldpath);
      var newpath = 'F:/change path to your project dir/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      mv(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }enter code here
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this problem, you can rewrite as:

```
fs.writeFile(path_where_to_write, file, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err; /*do something else.*/
});
/*and then Remove the file from tmp location*/
fs.unlink(tempPath);
```

and for multiple files, you could iterate this block based on length of files.

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
console.log(oldpath);
var newpath = 'F:/your folder name/' + files.filetoupload.name;
fs.readFile(oldpath, function (err, data) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('File read!');

// Write the file
fs.writeFile(newpath, data, function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
res.end();
console.log('File written!');
});

// Delete the file
fs.unlink(oldpath, function (err) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('File deleted!');
});
});
});
} else {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form- 
data">');
res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
res.write('<input type="submit">');
res.write('</form>');
return res.end();
}
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer. OP will learn much more from that than just copy-pasting the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use fs.writeFileSync
otherwise oldfile can be deleted before copied

```
fs.writeFileSync(newpath, data, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
    res.end();
    console.log('File written!');
});

// Delete the file
fs.unlink(oldpath, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File deleted!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when your temp folder is in a different drive and Node code is in a different drive.

It will throw this error.

Solution is in another StackOverflow question .

[What does the "EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206198/what-does-the-exdev-cross-device-link-not-permitted-error-mean)

solution from this post :

As per the new NodeJS, the solution is  don`t move, copy it

```
fs.copyFileSync(oldpath, newpath);
fs.unlink(oldpath,()=>{});
```

My windows 11 is in SSD and my Codes are in HDD.  The uploaded image will be downloaded in windows drive and I am trying to move it to HDD.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Its working within same disc(drive) path means within c:/ , Error occurred if new path disk drive is different from temp path disk drive.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error when using docker volumes.

The previous solutions did not work for me as I had to edit the framework I used, namely adminjs, and its upload-feature.

I wanted to store images in the local storage (images folder), while the app was running in a docker container.

I just created a directory called tmp inside my local storage inside that images folder, and added TMP, TEMP, TMPDIR and TEMPDIR environment variables with value of the created tmp folder. Value looks like this: "/app/images/tmp"

The docker run command I used:
docker run --name my-app -v /home/user/images:/app/images

Hope, this works for the others as well.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can resole this problem as.

1. install mv by command

   ```
   npm install mv --save
   ```
2. add mv in your nodejs file

   ```
   var mv = require('mv');
   ```
3. move file as:

   ```
   mv('source_file', 'destination_file,' function(err) {
       if (err) { throw err; }
   console.log('file moved successfully');
   };
   ```