# What does the "EXDEV: cross-device link not permitted" error mean?

Tags: node.js, libuv

What does this error actually mean? What is a "cross-device link"?

It is mentioned on [this libuv page](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/errors.html) but it doesn't give any details beyond "cross-device link not permitted".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is used for EXDEV on Linux:

See `man rename` manpage:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html

> EXDEV  oldpath and newpath are not on the same mounted filesystem.
>                 (Linux permits a filesystem to be mounted at multiple points,
>                 but rename() does not work across different mount points, even
>                if the same filesystem is mounted on both.)

This error is also used when there is `ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE` on Windows, see:

- https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/win/error.c#L166

For more info see:

- http://errorco.de/win32/winerror-h/error_not_same_device/0x80070011/

> winerror.h 0x80070011
>   `#define ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE`
>   The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive.

Answer (score 41):

It sounds like you're trying to rename a file across "device" (partition) boundaries.

Say that `/tmp` is a different partition than `/`. That means that you're not allowed to do this:

```
fs.rename('/tmp/myfile.txt', '/myfile.txt', ...)
```

(the same applies to `fs.renameSync()` as well, obviously)

If you want to do that, you need to first *copy* the file to its new location, and subsequently remove the old file. There are modules, like [`mv`](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-mv), that can help you with that.

Comment: Using the combination of **copyFile** and **unlink** in the File System module should also do the trick.

Comment: @AmirSyafrudin true, but `fs.copyFile` didn't exist at the time I wrote this answer :D

Comment: Indeed. Just wanted to add it in case any newbies such as myself stumbled upon your answer. :)

Comment: Code example for this solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44146825/5701

Comment: @SeanO with the additional remark that it reads the entire file into memory first

Answer (score 17):

I guess you are trying to copy a file from `/temp` folder since the form. I solved it coping, not renaming

```
        fs.copyFile(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
            res.end();
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for they guys who are using Linux this happens when your old path i.e. `/tmp` and new path are on different partitions or disks.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 21 and was trying this example [https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp] and get the same error. I have 1 partition on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i change the code from

```
for (const file of files) {
            const tempPath = file[1].filepath;
            await fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath + file[1].originalFilename);
        }
```

To the following  code

```
  for (const file of files) {
      const tempPath = file[1].filepath;
      await fs.copyFile(tempPath, targetPath + file[1].originalFilename);
      await fs.rm(tempPath);
    }
```

and it work fine for me

I think the issue is we cannot move the temp file directly from node

Answer (score 0):

In my case using Node v16.20 I changed:

```
await fs.promises.rename(appPath, targetDir)
```

to

```
await fs.promises.cp(appPath, targetDir, {
    recursive: true,
})
await fs.promises.rm(appPath, {
    recursive: true,
})
```