# Get file data to parse on server

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-upload, buffer

i am trying to do a simple pdf file upload.

i used [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) to do the job on uploading the file to the server, everything ok here, the problem arrives that i need to create the file with the buffer that i receive, basicly i need to store the files on the server. How can i do that?

**At the moment in my server i am receiving this data:**

```
{ name: 'sda.pdf',
  data: <Buffer 25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 35 0d 25 e2 e3 cf d3 0d 0a 31 20 30 20 6f 62 6a 0d 3c 3c 2f 4d 65 74 61 64 61 74 61 20 32 20 30 20 52 2f 4f 43 50 72 6f 70 65 72 ... >,
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/pdf',
  mv: [Function: mv] }
```

**i log the data on the upload route:**

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.files.curriculum);
});
```

any help?

Comment: Hey, did you see the 'full example' on this page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

Comment: i still get this error: {"errno":-4058,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"C:\\Users\\FilipeCosta\\Desktop\\easyRH\\files\\CV-FILIPECOSTA.pdf"}

Comment: Does the directory where you place your file exist? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552824/error-enoent-when-renaming-file-in-node-express-app

Comment: yeah but i still get the absolute path at the top

Comment: Okay, the error says 'syscall': 'open'. So maybe it's trying to open the file and then put the data into it. Maybe it helps to check if the file exists in the first place and if so, write.. otherwise create the file and then write to it.

Comment: i am trying to pass the file from client side to back side using the form

Comment: Yes, I talked about the procedure on the serverside.

Comment: i check it :   if(!req.files) {
    return res.status(400).send("No Files were uploaded");
  }

Comment: it doesn't hit there

Comment: Ah, I see there is a misunderstanding, I'm talking about the file in your datasystem, eg. C:\\some_path\\myfile.pdf. The error says: 'syscall': 'open'. So I guess, it throws the error when the file does not exist, so it can't write the data to it.

Comment: because i basicly want to send it to the server, create the file i just receive the buffer and then move it maybe, how can i create it with the buffer data? i thaught the function moved and created the file automaticly, any tip?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the `mv` function on the `express-fileupload` object. Use this function to put the file where you want on your server. (from the express-fileupload readme)

```
sampleFile.mv('/somewhere/on/your/server/filename.jpg', function(err) {
    if (err)
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    res.send('File uploaded!');
});
```

Comment: i still don't have the file, i get this error: {"errno":-4058,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"C:\\Users\\FilipeCosta\\Desktop\\easyRH\\files\\CV-FILIPECOSTA.pdf"}

Comment: Can you provided an example of your `.mv` function call?